# asp.net web api: accessing uploaded file stream

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api application which is acting as a Relay to a wcf web service. In certain scenarios I want to upload large files. The methods in the wcf service accept files as stream. 
 I do not want to save the files on my intermediate server I want to access the stream of the uploaded file and provide it to the wcf method so that the data is directly streamed to the wcf service.

Here is similar scenario when client is downloading the file

```
using (IProductsChannel channel = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel())
            {
                result.Content = new StreamContent(channel.GetFile());
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
                return result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is at least one way of doing it. using the HTTPContext the only problem with this one is that it is not good for unit testing so we have to abstract it out in the final solution.

```
 var file =   HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];


            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            using (IProductsChannel channel = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel())
            {
                channel.SaveFile(file.InputStream);
            }

            return  new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
```